# Jump for jnz despite both values being equal

Tags: assembly

SO I have trouble understanding the following code:

```
cmp rbx, rbp
jnz short somelocation
[other instructions]
```

I'm debugging the program and set a breakpoint right at the jnz command. I inspect my rbx and rbp stacks and the first element on the stack is identical for both (0 and 0). And yet the program jumps. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Are you trying to compare register contents, or are you trying to use the registers as pointers?

Comment: `rbx` and `rbp` are 64 bits stored on the CPU chip, the "registers". The CPU will not contact/read memory for `cmp rbx,rbp`, it will just compare the values in registers. If you have in them pointers to two different memory locations, only pointer values (which are 64b integers too). If you want to read memory, you must use brackets like `cmp [rbx], [rbp]`, but that's illegal combination of two memory operands together, so you must first load one value into some spare register, like `mov rax,[rbx] ; load 8 bytes from address rbx` `cmp rax,[rbp] ; compare with 8 bytes at address rbp`.

Comment: And btw, you have to respect the "element" size to get correct compare, if the element is just single byte, then `movzx eax,byte [rbx] ; reset full 64b of rax, but load only single byte` `cmp al,[rbp] ; compare with other byte` is probably most performant on modern x86-64, unless you know you will compare several values and you can use SIMD (SSE2/etc) instructions to compare several "packed bytes" at the same time.